# how to execute adb shell command in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ui-automation, calabash-android

I am trying to execute calabash-android test, in which i have one scenario that uses adb shell..and hence i have created method for the same in ruby as follows:

```
def mock_barcode_scan(barcode = '676767')
    adb "shell am broadcast -a com.zz.zz.MockBarcodeReadEvent -e BARCODE #{barcode}"
  end
```

now when i try to access this method, NO action is performed .. and scenario fails for this step ... note: i am using windows 7 and executing this test using git bash..

Comment: are you able access adb on command line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use command system()
example:
`irb`

`2.3.1 :001 > system("adb devices")`

print:
`List of devices attached`